# How to ssh into raspberry pi when wifi auto switches to 5GHz

Tags: wifi, ssh, terminal

My router uses Smart Connect which like mesh, allows the router's 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz bands to use the same wireless settings and switches over to the best connection in traffic.

When my headless rpi is on the 2.4 GHz, I can ssh into it just fine. However, when it switches to 5 Ghz, the ssh connection freezes and I have to go into my router and turn off the 5GHz connection and reconnect.

How can I ssh into it when it is on the 5GHz band? In other words, what would I type differently in the command line?

[Edit - new question]
I tried assigning a fixed ip address to the device on my router. But this did not work. So it turns out, the switch between 2.4 and 5GHz might not the reason that I cannot ssh into the pi, because I tried turning off 5Ghz signal and it's still not connecting.

However, when I tried typing the ssh like this:

```
ssh pi@192.168.0.100
```

instead of like this:

```
ssh pi@hostname.local
```

Then I was able to connect. So the new question is, why is it *sometimes* freezing / hanging when I type the command as hostname, and is there a setting I can change to fix it.

Comment: I used both. When I swtich from 2.4 to 5G GHz, I change router  password.

Comment: Does your router allow connections between 5GHz devices or does it have "wireless isolation" active on that SSID? Check the router home pages at http://192.168.0.1 , http://192.168.0.254, http://192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.1.254 (whichever is applicable to your home network).

Comment: @toyotaSupra can you elaborate?

Comment: @Dougie yes it does allow connections between 5GHz devices.

Comment: @et59black. On RPi you have to change password. Disconnected 2.4. then activate password on 5 GHz and vice versa. That what Dougie saying.

Comment: no it isn't @toyotaSupra

Comment: @toyotaSupra both bands have a pw, but they are the same pw. Are you saying they need to be different?

Answer (score 1):

i think during the switch to 5GHz network, your rpi receives a new IP address. I guess thats the reason why connection interrupts.
So i would suggest to assign a fixed ip address to your rpi on your router.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that should be a suitable solution. @Jet59black, could you confirm wether this worked for you or not?

Comment: @JJandke see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting from a machine also connected to WiFi?  Does the Router have "AP Isolation" enabled?  If so, you may want to look into disabling AP Isolation between 2.4GHz and 5GHz.

When you set up your Router, it has features to help secure your network.  One such method is to separate your WiFi APs such that machines on different APs cannot communicate as if they were on the same LAN.  Sometimes this isolation is enabled between the different bands as well as different SSIDs.

---

Otherwise, does the Raspberry Pi have Internet access when it switches over to 5GHz?  Would be good to diagnose and add this detail to your question if my suggestion doesn't work for you.

Additionally, are you connecting via DNS or IP?  Can you confirm that when you go from 2.6GHz to 5GHz the IP of the machine stays the same, or that you adjust your connection to the appropiate IP?

Comment: To answer your questions:

Comment: 1) Yes, I am on a machine that is also on the wifi. 2) AP Isolation is not enabled. 3) Yes the Pi has internet access when it switches over to 5GHz. 4) I am connecting via Dynamic IP, but it also shows a DNS--sorry not sure what you mean here or how to check that.

Answer (score 0):

ssh doesn't know (or care) WHAT band your WiFi is using or whether you are using Ethernet.

Your problem is elsewhere.

Most likely just a dropped ssh connection.

Have you tried just reconnecting?

If not post output (into you question) of.

```
ip a && ip r
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the output as you suggested (above). Also I am running the rpi headless, so only means of talking to it is via the ssh connection, therefore I cannot just reconnect -- I'd have to restart the pi, and that disrupts the programs I am running on it.

Comment: You have NOT posted the output. There is absolutely no point in obscuring private IP addresses.

Comment: You DO NOT have to restart anything to re establish connection.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know there's no point in obscuring ip addresses -- just being cautious, no need to yell. So, that is the output I got. What are you looking for, do you need to see the private ip's?